# wp query loop pattern

Tags: wordpress, loops, nested

I'm trying to display posts in a pattern that foreach one post it will display two small posts

like this:

big post

small  small

big post

small  small

big post

small  small

what i did so far is nested loop

```
 $main_args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => '15',
       'paged' => $page,
       'orderby' => 'date',
 );


 $main_query = new WP_Query( $main_args );
 if ( $main_query->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $main_query->have_posts() ) {
            $main_query->the_post();



            wp_reset_postdata();

             $small_args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'post',
                     'posts_per_page' => 2,
                     'orderby' => 'date',
                     'order' => 'DESC',
             );
             $small_query = new WP_Query( $small_args );

              if ( $small_query->have_posts() ) {
                     while ( $small_query->have_posts() ) {
                           $small_query->the_post();

                      }
              }// end loop
              wp_reset_postdata();
       }
} 

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

the problem with this code is that for some reason the nested loop duplicates the same post again and again

need help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query will not work due to the fact that you use `wp_reset_postdata();` each time. Instead, try to use the loop for one and then use `$wpdb` for the small queries and use an offset to tell the loop which one should be the first, 4th, 7th, 10th etc.

Ill post my version of how i would do it in a minute but have a look into [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and maybe you could figure it out on your own

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you send this snippets?  I'm struggling to get it working...